# uploading postgresql db dumps to heroku has failed

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I generated my `db dump` file in my project and I tried to upload it to heroku with this command in the command line:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore "https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump"   postgres://xxxxxx:xxx@xxxxx:5432/xxxxx    --app my-app
```

but am facing this error:

```
!    Unknown database:
 !    postgres://xxxxxx:xxx@xxxxx:5432/xxxxx    --app my-app. Valid
 !    options are: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL, DATABASE_URL
```

But the database URL or Heroku_postgres_Bronze_URL am using does exist, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this

$pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d appname_development heroku-db.dump